# Stormpath Spring Boot integration - context repeats

Tags: spring-boot, stormpath

I'm trying to add the Stormpath login workflow to my Spring Boot app, running under a context of /api which I've defined in my application.properties with server.context-path=/api.

When I hit a restricted path, I get the Stormpath login page with a "next" request param of http://localhost:8080/api/login?next=%2Fapi%2F. After a successful login, this causes my context to be repeated: http://localhost:8080/api/api/ . Is there a way for me to get around this?

I'm using stormpath-default-spring-boot-starter version 1.1.1

Thank you

Comment: You have discovered a bug in the SDK. See: https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/issues/1061. The intention is to get it fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed and released in version `1.1.2`. See https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/issues/1061.